# What is the sample size in this experiment?

Tags: self-study, sample-size, descriptive-statistics

We have to determine the sample size in the following experiment.
We are trying to determine the concentration in which a combination of drugs works the best against cancer cells.
This involved cell cultures of prostate cancer cells which were exposed to 7 different combinations of drug A with drug Z including the control. The experiment was carried out four times. Each time, three samples from each culture were analysed. 
Can anyone help? I have been trying to determine it for at least two hours now but my lecturer's note have only confused me and every time I decide the correct answer I change my mind in minutes. She gave us another experiment as an example and that has only complicated things. I thought sample size might be 3, 4, 7, 21 or 84 so far. I kind of feel the question is really easy but I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Cross Validated.  If this is a homework problem or class assignment, please add the `self-study` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), which includes information on etiquette for asking for help on self study questions

Comment: The term "sample size" is meaningless in such a complex situation. Among other difficulties, it is not clear whether this is considered four separate iterations of one experiment or if the four replications are to be considered a single experiment. Also, insufficient information is available concerning how the cancer cells were obtained.  Presumably different cells are involved in each experiment and each drug, but we aren't told whether these cells were obtained from one source or different sources. Thus, it appears that most of your possible answers could be justified.